# sequence does not exist, hibernate and JPA 2.1

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am getting an error saying

```
`Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist`
```

This error happens when I try to create a user.

```
  @RequestMapping(method = POST)
    public UserDto createUser(@RequestBody userDto user) {
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(user);

        return Preconditions.checkNotNull(service.create(user));
    }
```

I am however able to `delete` and `get` just not `create` nor `update`. What is also frustrating is I get no error when trying to `update`, it just doesn't so it.

I am not getting any real lead on where to look. I have tried many different methods to resolve this with no avail.

I found a post that had this:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQUENCE1")
@SequenceGenerator(name="SEQUENCE1", sequenceName="SEQUENCE1", allocationSize=1)
private int user_id;
```

At this link: [SOF link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30178845/error-ora-02289-sequence-does-not-exist-org-hibernate-exception-sqlgrammarex)

It is complaining about this entity which I generated with netbeans and I am currently using Intellij. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_sequences WHERE sequence_name = 'SHOP_SEQ';`? Do the same for `CAMPAIGN_SEQ`.

Comment: Please add the code sample where you create Campaign entity

Comment: can you debug the exact query which is automatically executed wihtin Dao layer ?

Comment: @SHIVOMPANDEY I am outputting the query. I declared this is application.properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code that creates new `Campaign` entity seems to be incorrect.

```
public CampaignDto create(CampaignDto campaignDto) {
    Campaign campaign = mapper.mapReverse(campaignDto);

    System.out.println(campaign.toString());

    // Following 2 lines must be added to obtain and use managed Shop entity
    Shop existingShop = shopRepository.findOne(campaignDto.getShopId());
    campaign.setShop(existingShop);

    campaign = campaignRepository.save(campaign);
    CampaignDto createdCampaign = mapper.map(campaign);

    return createdCampaign;
}
```

Comment: @Drew1208  make sure that it was created in DB, otherwise you need to create it manually. `CREATE SEQUENCE CAMPAIGN_SEQ; COMMIT;` (or whatever name you use)

Comment: Emmm, `DEV_STAG.CAMPAIGN_CHECK_STATUS_TYPE` seems to be irrelevant to the code/scheme that you've posted so far. What is inside this constraint? How do you insert Shop record?

Comment: Of course you can play with different code combinations, but the root of problem is within your DB since you couldn't event insert a **shop_table** record correctly. Try to truncate `shop_table` (or whatever named) and insert first shop `insert into shop_table (id, ...) values (shop_seq.nextval, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might not be setting `Campaign.shopId` field when creating new `Campaign`.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "SHOP_ID", referencedColumnName = "SHOP_ID")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Shop shopId;
```

You might want to rename this field to just `shop` to make it clear what it holds as it's not just an identifier.

Depending on how you are persisting new objects you might need to add `CascadeType.ALL` on `@ManyToOne` to ensure that a new `Shop` is persisted together with a new `Campaign`.

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `SequenceGenerator` and JPA dialect supports `BigDecimal` data type correctly? Looks like it currently fails to persist `BigDecimal` value. This might depend on the JPA dialect but it's generally easier to define `id` fields as `long`.

Comment: Did you persist the `Shop` object before persisting `Campaign`? If so please add the code that shows how are you doing it. Your mapping in your question still doesn't use cascades as suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your application property file and put 
**hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=true;** It might be helpful Hibernate created this sequence and added a new row